# Writing an Algorithm for Tiling a Floor Using Python

Tags: python, function

I was trying to do my homework but ı can not make it ı researched many topics about that but ı can't find the answer so that ı need help.

Our teacher wants this; 
Make a plan for tiling a rectangular bathroom floor with alternating black and white tiles measuring 4 × 4 inches. The floor dimensions, measured in inches, are multiples of 4

Determine the inputs and outputs.

The inputs are the floor dimensions (length × width), measured in inches.

The output is a tiled floor.

Step2) Break down the problem into smaller tasks.

A natural subtask is to lay one row of tiles. If you can solve that, then you can solve the problem by laying one row next to the other, starting from a wall, until you reach the opposite wall. How do you lay a row? Start with a tile at one wall. If it is white, put a black one next to it. If it is black, put a white one next to it. Keep going until you reach the opposite wall. The row will contain width / 4 tiles.

Step-3) Describe each subtask in pseudocode.

Suppose you want to tile an area measuring 20 × 12 inches. The first step is to place a black tile in the northwest corner.

So btw ı am so sorry, ı could not understand anything and our teacher didin't tell anything about that topic.

```
def place_tiles( room_length, room_width, tile_dim ):
"""
Place alternating colored tiles in the specified room and return the layout
of the tiling. The length and width of the room are provided by the first two
parameters, and tile_dim provides the dimension of each tile, which we will
assume to be a square.
"""
# We can replace each row of tiles as a list. Therefore, the entire placement
# can be represented as a list of lists.
placement = []
# COMPLETE THE REST OF THE CODE BEFORE NEXT TIME
```

We are studying from this book;

Horstman And Necaise 2016 Python for everyone

Comment: As the assignment already suggests: First make code to place one tile, then to make one row and then the whole floor. You can ask if you get stuck at a particular issue.

Comment: actually ı don't know anything about this thats why ı can not effort or show some code. But  ı can write  

1. 0. 1. 0.
1. 0. 1. 0.
1. 0. 1. 0.

 n x n matrix

Comment: If you can write such a matrix you should at least show that code.

Comment: Referring to the code currently shown as answer: I don't see where numbers 1, 2, 3, 4 are required by the assignment. What exactly the assignment means by marking tiles as black or white is unclear. Maybe 0 and 1  as "black" and "white" would do or replacing the numbers by strings.

Comment: If you are allowed to use numpy, there is [repeat](https://numpy.org/doc/1.17/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html#numpy.repeat) to stretch the current 0101... to the requested 0000111100001111... (one call for each axis).

Comment: thx for comments, still ı can't make it. yes ı can use numpy.

Comment: You just create the checkered pattern for a quarter of the requested width and height and stretch it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

İt's to late to say but, Finally ı understand and ı writed an algorithm thank you @Micheal Butscher

```
def place_tiles(room_length, room_width , tile_dim):
    placement = []

    num_of_tiles_per_row = int(room_length / tile_dim)
    num_of_tiles_per_col = int(room_width / tile_dim)
    prev_tile = None

    for c in range(num_of_tiles_per_col):
        cur_row_tiles = []


        for r in range(num_of_tiles_per_row):
            if prev_tile and prev_tile == "w":
                cur_row_tiles.append("b")
                prev_tile = "b"

            else:
                cur_row_tiles.append("w")
                prev_tile = "w"
        placement.append(cur_row_tiles)
        prev_tile = cur_row_tiles[0]
    return placement

place_tiles(4,4,1)
```